# Nginx Ingress rules not find a match

Tags: regex, kubernetes, regex-negation, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I'm struggling on an Ingress configuration in yaml because the pattern matching seems not to work.

I would like the **frontend-lb** ClusterIP Service for the frontend deployment to respond to any of these:

- https://example.com
- https://example.com/home
- https://example.com/login
- ... any other **without /api/**

And the **backend-lb** ClusterIP Service for the backend deployment to respond to any of these:

- https://example.com/api/...

The yaml for the ingress rules is the following:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  tls:
    - secretName: example-com-tls
      hosts:
        - example.com
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /api
        backend:
          serviceName: gateway-lb
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: frontend-lb
          servicePort: 80
```

The result is that every backend url is recognized as a frontend url and gives back 404 Not Found.

I've tried many other regexp and also I've tried to exclude ***/api*** in the frontend path **(!?api).*** but with no success.

**UPDATE:**

What I see with the logs **it's like in the backend the url path gets blanked** because if I call:

https://example.com/api/javalin-api-gateway/login

I get this error:

> Not found. Request is below context-path (context-path:
> '/javalin-api-gateway')

While when I call the frontend with a specific url path:

https://example.com/home

The ***/home*** controller is effectively called (it doesn't get blanked).

If I call the backend service directly (if the service is a LoadBalancer) with the same url:
http://192.168.64.17:31186/javalin-api-gateway/login
I get the right response, signal that the backend part is working properly.
How is possible that only the backend service doesn't receive the complete path?

Comment: What if you explicitly define `pathType: Prefix`?

Comment: just tryed and doesn't work (even if in the docs it's told the match would be the longest one)

Comment: I've tried also to add /fe/ as prefix for the frontend, but now asking for (https://example.com/fe/home) gives me 404 to the frontend too. Why?

Comment: Habe you tried to remove the rewrite-target annotaion?

Comment: yes, now, same 404

Comment: what happens when you change "/api" to "/javalin-api-gateway" without rewrites?

Comment: YES THAT IS THE POINT! If you write it me down as an answer I'll check as the right one

Comment: Can you elaborate? Does it work when you change the path in ingress manifest from `/api` to `/javalin-api-gateway`?